# How does the order of concurrent promises work in an asynchronous function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, concurrency, promise

I noticed an example of concurrent promises from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

```
async function foo() {
   const p1 = new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve('1'), 1000))
   const p2 = new Promise((_,reject) => setTimeout(() => reject('2'), 500))
   const results = [await p1, await p2];
}
foo().catch(() => {}) // Attempt to swallow all errors...
```

MDN states:

> in the following code an unhandled promise rejection error will be thrown, even if a .catch handler has been configured further along the promise chain. This is because p2 will not be "wired into" the promise chain until control returns from p1.

What exactly does this mean? If `await` waits for `p1`'s promise to resolve first, why then does the rejection error occur for `p2`? I am very new to asynchronous function and am grateful for any new insights!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the interpreter isn't waiting for p2's promise to resolve while it's still waiting for p1. Before it runs across the line `await p2`, the `p2` is essentially dangling - it's not connected to anything else *until* it gets `await`ed. So, if p2 throws before it's connected to a `.catch` - either via a `.catch` in the function itself, or via an `await`, connecting it to an outside `.catch` - you'll get an unhandled rejection.

Another way of illustrating the same problem, using only a single Promise:

```
function foo() {
   const p2 = new Promise((_,reject) => setTimeout(() => reject('2'), 500))
   setTimeout(() => {
     p2.catch(() => {});
   }, 1000);
}
foo();
```

In your snippet's example, p1 is only important in that it causes a delay before the `await p2` expression is encountered. In my example above, the `setTimeout` is doing something similar - it's attaching a `.catch` handler *after* the promise has rejected, resulting in an unhandled rejection.

Answer (score 1):

Adding some `console.log` statements to your program will help you see order of operations

```js
async function foo() {
   console.log("foo")
   const p1 = new Promise((resolve) => {
     console.log("p1 promise")
     setTimeout(_ => {
       console.log("p1 resolve")
       resolve('1')
     }, 1000)
   })
   const p2 = new Promise((_,reject) => {
     console.log("p2 promise")
     setTimeout(_ => {
       console.log("p2 reject")
       reject('2')
     }, 500)
   })
   console.log("results") 
   return [
     (console.log("await p1"), await p1),     
     (console.log("await p2"), await p2)
   ]
   
}
foo().then(console.log, console.error)
```

**output**

| order | console.log |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | foo |
| 2 | p1 promise |
| 3 | p2 promise |
| 4 | results |
| 5 | await p1 |
| 6 | p2 reject |
| 7 | p1 resolve |
| 8 | await p2 |
| 9 | Error: 2 |

**explanation**

1. So when we run `foo`, it's expected that we see message **1**, *"foo"*, first, as that is the first line of the program.
2. Next `p1` is created and we see message **2**, *"p1 promise"*. This shows you that the `body` of `new Promise(... => body)` is run immediately.
3. Next `p2` is created and we see message **3**, *"p2 promise"*, following the same explanation as above.
4. Next we see message **4**, *"results"*. If you expected to see the messages inside the `setTimeout`, those are delayed in the event queue and we will see them later. This is the express purpose of `setTimeout`
5. Next is message **5**, *"await p1"*, and we are waiting for `p1` to resolve.
6. While we are waiting for `p1` to resolve, `p2` rejects and we see message **6**, *"p2 reject"*.
7. `p1` finally resolves and we see message **7**, *"p1 resolve"*.
8. Next we move onto the final value in the result array and we wee message **8**, *"await p2"*. `p2` has already been fulfilled at this point, and it has resulted in a rejected error. At this point `foo` immediately exits and the call to `foo()` results in a rejected promise. If there was code after this point, it would not be run. This is the same as `throw`ing an error in synchronous code.
9. Finally we see message **9**, *"Error: 2"*, which is the result of `console.error` catching the rejected promise returned by `foo()`